# Can Raspbian stretch lite (latest) run on a Raspberry Pi 1B?

Tags: raspbian, pi-1

I have a couple of old Raspberry Pi 1Bs and was going to repurpose it for something simple. I decided to make a new flash drive for it using the latest Raspbian Stretch Lite image 2018-04-18. The flash drive seems to be written correctly, but when I try to boot the image, it gets stuck right after the keyboard detection on the line:

```
[  40.046049] random: crng init done
```

Then it just sits there indefinitely (have waited several minutes). I've tried a few different power supplies and cables to be sure. All I have hooked up is a keyboard and HDMI display. I've also confirmed that the Pi itself still works as I was able to boot to an older Raspbian version on a different flash card. Could be the flash card to I guess.

But just to confirm, will the latest Raspbian images work with the older Pi 1s?

Comment: run the `badblocks` on your SD card, make sure you check writing as well as reading ability, because likely your card may be corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Raspbian will run on ALL models of Pi.

The message you quoted relates to the initiation of entropy in the random generator, and has nothing to do with the problem - it is just the last command run.

I have experienced similar issues which are caused by corrupted SD Cards which prevent the OS from completing the boot.

I suggest you:-

1. Verify the checksum of the downloaded image.
2. Format the SD Card - use a full format (or just create a new
   partition table) before copying - you don't specify what method you
   are using.

Normally, if copying am image there is no need to format first, but some of the smart copy programs are impacted by disk errors.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to run since the first raspberry pi and the pi zero use the same processor.